# Jupyter notebook での import について

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Jupyter notebookでreaderというファイルを作りました。
それを下の画像のようにimportしたいんですがエラーになってしまいます
また保存したものが.ipynbとついてくるんですがこれはどういう意味ですか。
回答をいただければありがたいです
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: atomエディターを使ってreader.pyで保存するとエラーが出ませんでした

Comment: jupyter notebookで`pwd`を実行してみて下さい。これがcurrent directoryなのですが、`reader`と異なるとimport error出る場合があります。

Answer (score 1):

.ipynb は、 jupyter notebook の保存ファイル形式です。中身をエディタ(atom など) で開くとわかると思いますが、これは json 形式で notebook の中身を記したもので、 python のスクリプトの形式にはなっていません。

notebook から利用したいコードがある場合には、なので、 .py 形式で普通のプログラムとして保存したうえで、 notebook 上で import する必要があります。
(自分の記憶ですと、おまじないみたいなコードを書かないと、notebook にローカルのファイルは import できなかったような気がしているのですが、問題なく import できた、とのことですので、私の記憶違いかもしれません。)

#### 追記@2017/07/16

notebook の内容から、python コード部分のみを抜き出して保存するには、対象の notebook を開いた状態から File -> Download as -> python (.py) 取得できる模様です。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。jupyter notebookで保存したファイルを.py形式で普通のプログラムとして保存すればjupyter notebook上でimportできるということでしょうか？それをするやり方はわかりませんか？それはかなりややこしいでしょうか？

Comment: @user23690 notebook の上で記述した python コードを、普通の python コードとして、 .py ファイルとして保存する方法、、をお聞きになっていますでしょうか？ それとも .py ファイルの import の方法でしょうか？

Comment: .pyとして保存する方法でした。.pyで保存ができたらimportでインポートできますか？

Comment: @user23690 mention を飛ばし忘れていました。。 1. 回答に追記しました 2. 保存した .py ファイルは、そのままだと import できない可能性が高いと考えています。その場合は教えてください。